# Where did Nyssa-Vex end up after zeta-beaming herself?

Tags: dc, krypton-2018

In the season 2 finale (episode 10) of *Krypton* TV series, Nyssa-Vex

> zeta-beamed herself to find Sardath who could help find her child Jor-El.

But, the forbidden zeta-beam device which was hacked by Adam Strange was shown as a quirky device and even Adam Strange wasn't sure where the Zeta-beam device would take Nyssa-Vex across time and space.

Where did Nyssa-Vex end up after zeta-beaming herself?

**Note:** As the TV series has now been cancelled, its future is not defined. So, this question can't be closed as per future works policy. I am looking for answers from other sources (e.g. [Plot of first episode of season 3 has been released](https://www.denofgeek.com/us/tv/dc-entertainment/282914/krypton-season-3-news)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe she is on Rann. this is based off her conversation with Adam in Episode 10 of Season 2

> **Adam:** There was a time I would've gone back, damn, with this and hit the undo button on what happened to me.
>   **Nyssa:** You still could.
>   Adam: No, this little dick-puncher comes with consequences. The universe-ending kind. 
>   **Nyssa:** How did you get that? 
>   **Adam:** It was given to me by this inventor named Sardath. You know, dude's so smart he could tutor Val. I mean, there is nothing about space-time he doesn't know.
>   **Nyssa:** So where is Sardath now? 
>   **Adam:** My guess he's on his home planet Rann. Hell of a planet. Unparalleled technology. It was kind of the Zeta-Beam's default destination, so I got to know it pretty well and his daughter, Alanna

...

> **Nyssa:** The Zeta-Beam can transport me across the universe to wherever Brainiac has my son.
>   **Adam:** Nyssa, you don't even know how to use that thing. The landing alone can 
>   **Nyssa:** You've already told me everything I need to know about it.

Soruce: [springfieldspringfield - Krypton (2018) s02e10 Episode Script](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=krypton-2018&episode=s02e10)

Now Val developed Deep Space Scanners and found Braniac with them on his way to Krypton, however in Episode 8 of Season 2 after Braniac took Jor Seg tried to find Braniac's Skull Ship but

> Seg! You've been at this for hours. You scanned as far as the deep space sensors can go and found nothing

and Adam makes Sardath out to be smarter than Val.

Also there's that Nyssa said that Adam told her everything she needed to know about the Zeta Beam. the only thing useful that he has said she could use to work it is that Zeta Beam as a default destinations which is Sardath's home planet Rann.

---

this is also confirmed in the link in the question sourced from [the Writer/Director's tweet](https://twitter.com/CamWelsh_/status/1163441772564901888)

> Thanks for the reminder. I saw the speculation online and wanted to clear up. It was a squad of Thanagarians that Nyssa saw. She was on a Thanagarian occupied Rann, and we would have gotten heavily into the Rann/Thanagar war, with The Omega Men (not Darkseid) the wild card. Sigh.

Comment: The last part (tweet) is the only required citation.